# Will a raw socket receive everything that is coming in through the internet layer irrespective of port number?

Tags: network-programming

A raw socket has no port numbers since it is an internet layer entity. So, if a program opens raw socket, will it be able to receive every data what comes in the computer from outside, irrespective of which application wants it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, reading from a raw socket reads all incoming packets. This is how packet sniffers are implemented.

Comment: Ok, then what about the applications which are already bound to some port number? If my raw socket receives their data, how will they get it?

Comment: The data will go to both the raw socket and the application that is bound to some port number. This behavior is required in order for packet sniffers to not interfere with the applications that they may be monitoring.